# ILMerge The assembly was not merged in correctly. It is still listed as an external... [Given solutions doesn't work]

Tags: c#, dll, ilmerge

I'm trying to merge few dlls into one dll. I'm using ILMerge. It was working properly, but after I've added new code and new dlls, it gives me an exception, while running ILMerge.

The libraries are merging good. Only when I add my main dll, created in Visual Studio, it throws an Exception.

I get such error:

```
An exception occurred during merging:
ILMerge.Merge: The assembly 'YamadaGS1_128' was not merged in correctly. 
It is still listed as an external reference in the target assembly.
    in ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
    in ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

I tryied to add `/closed` option, or change `Assembly Name`, but it gives the same error.

I've added ADODB code into my project. I'm not sure, was there any other changes.  But ofter code modification, I get such error.

Please help. Thanks.
Mike.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found solution for my problem.

I had to set `embedded interop type` of `ADODB` to `false` in VisualStudio.

Thanks. Mike